# three.js object is black before texture loads - can I change this behavior?

Tags: three.js, textures

I am very new to `three.js`. In my project you can move through a series of planes with cross section images of an object. The problem is that the material doesn't load right away and moving up and down too quickly causes some of the planes to display black.  I need to change this behavior.  Is there a way to either

1. change some property so the plane is transparent - but the image should still be opaque when loaded
2. or don't display/render the plane at all until the texture is loaded?

I'm not at all sure I am on the right track, and I am hoping someone more experienced can suggest a specific fix.

Thanks!

Comment: if you are using THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture for loading textures, you can send a callback as third argument, in which you can, for example, add object with this texture to the scene.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if you already cleared this up but I made a handy little function to take care of this by modifying the opacity setting, the basic of which are:

```
function loadTexture( path ){

    var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( path, null, function() {
            mat.opacity = 1;
        } ),
        opacity: 0
    });

    return mat;
}
```